# Why use left multiplication to prove frame manifold is well-defined? Can $(M,\mathscr A)$ and $(M,\mathscr B)$ be diffeo, with identity not a diffeo?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, differential-geometry, manifolds, group-actions

My book is Connections, Curvature, and Characteristic Classes by Loring W. Tu (I'll call this Volume 3), a sequel to both Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology by Loring W. Tu and Raoul Bott (Volume 2) and An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu (Volume 1).

I refer to [Section 27.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re1WS.png) and to my previous question: [Manifold structure such that a bijection of sets becomes a diffeomorphism of manifolds? Group structure for group isomorphism?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3398697/manifold-structure-such-that-a-bijection-of-sets-becomes-a-diffeomorphism-of-man).

**Question A**: The following is my understanding of the part "Using the bijection...***frame manifold*** of the vector space $V$". Is this correct?

**Note**: I ask about frame manifold not frame bundle. $V$ is still finite $\mathbb R$-vector space of dimension $r$ and not a smooth $\mathbb R$-vector bundle of rank $r$.

1. For smooth manifolds $(M,\mathscr A)$ and $(M,\mathscr B)$ with the same underlying set $M$ and respective smooth atlases $\mathscr A$ and $\mathscr B$, it's possible that $(M,\mathscr A)$ and $(M,\mathscr B)$ are diffeomorphic but neither of the identity maps $id_{M,\mathscr A,\mathscr B}:$ $ (M,\mathscr A)$ $\to$ $(M,\mathscr B)$ and $id_{M,\mathscr B,\mathscr A}:$ $ (M,\mathscr B)$ $\to$ $(M,\mathscr A)$ are diffeomorphisms.

- 1.1 I think this is what [Problem 6.1 of Volume 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpDAz.png) (also the example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297573/are-manifold-subsets-submanifolds?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment6785567_3298394)) is an example of. For reference, [here's a solution given by Richard G. Ligo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62hHq.png).

2. We have a right, free and transitive (regular) action $\mu: Fr(V) \times GL(r, \mathbb R) \to Fr(V)$. For each $u \in Fr(V)$, we can define a map $\mu_u: GL(r, \mathbb R) \to Fr(V)$, $\mu_u(g) := \mu(u,g)$ that turns out to be a bijection between $Fr(V)$ and the manifold (and Lie group) $GL(r, \mathbb R)$
3. Let $v,w \in Fr(v)$. We consider $Fr_v(V) = (Fr(V),\mathscr A_v)$ and $Fr_w(V) = (Fr(V),\mathscr A_w)$ be smooth manifolds with the same underlying set $Fr(V)$ with $\mathscr A_v$ and $\mathscr A_w$ respectively uniquely determined by the bijections of sets $\mu_v: GL(r,\mathbb R) \to Fr(V)$ and $\mu_w: GL(r,\mathbb R) \to Fr(V)$ becoming (smooth) diffeomorphisms of (smooth) manifolds $\mu_v^d: GL(r,\mathbb R) \to Fr_v(V)$ and $\mu_w^d: GL(r,\mathbb R) \to Fr_w(V)$.
4. If each $Fr_v(V)$ and $Fr_w(V)$ are diffeomorphic, then it is already well-defined to say that we can make the set $Fr(V)$ into a (smooth) manifold called the frame manifold of $V$ by choosing the manifold that $Fr(V)$ becomes as $Fr_u(V)$ for any $u \in Fr(V)$, *in the sense* that even though we might have $Fr_v(V) \ne Fr_w(V)$, we have at least that $Fr_v(V)$ and $Fr_w(V)$ are diffeomorphic. So, the frame manifold is well-defined "up to diffeomorphism" or something.
5. We can show $Fr_v(V)$ and $Fr_w(V)$ are diffeomorphic by either $\mu_v^d \circ (\mu_w^d)^{-1}$ or its inverse.
6. Additionally, we can show that $id_{Fr(V),\mathscr A_v,\mathscr A_w}: (Fr(V),\mathscr A_v) \to (Fr(V),\mathscr A_w)$ and $id_{Fr(V),\mathscr A_w,\mathscr A_v}: (Fr(V),\mathscr A_w) \to (Fr(V),\mathscr A_v)$ are diffeomorphisms by noting $\mu_w = \mu_v \circ l_a$, where $a$ is the unique element of $GL(r,\mathbb R)$ such that $w=\mu(v,a)$.

- 6.1. Thus, left multiplication enables us to prove something stronger than that $Fr_v(V)$ and $Fr_w(V)$ are diffeomorphic: That $Fr_v(V)$ and $Fr_w(V)$ are diffeomorphic by either of the identity maps $id_{Fr(V),\mathscr A_v,\mathscr A_w}$ and $id_{Fr(V),\mathscr A_w,\mathscr A_v}$. Therefore, the frame manifold is well-defined *in an even stronger sense* than in (4) because $Fr_v(V)$ and  $Fr_w(V)$ are "identical" in the sense of Guess 1 or Guess 2 below.

**Question B**: (Assuming (1) is correct). What's the term, if any, to describe the manifolds $(M,\mathscr A)$ and $(M,\mathscr B)$ as diffeomorphic by the identity map, or alternatively what can we say about such $(M,\mathscr A)$ and $(M,\mathscr B)$?

- Guess 1: There is a term, and it is that they are "identical" in the sense that they are not "distinct", where "distinct" is in the sense of [Problem 6.1b of Volume 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpDAz.png). This is because we can say that the maximal (smooth) atlases $\mathscr M(\mathscr A)$ and $\mathscr M(\mathscr B)$ are equal (Note: The "$M$" of "$\mathscr M$" stands for "maximal" and does not refer to the underlying set $M$.). Thus, what Tu is trying to say is that $Fr_v(V)$ and $Fr_w(V)$ are not only diffeomorphic but actually "identical" i.e. $\mathscr M(\mathscr A_v)$ $=$ $\mathscr M(\mathscr A_w)$.
- Guess 2: It is not true in general that we can say that $\mathscr M(\mathscr A) = \mathscr M(\mathscr B)$. However, we can say that, for the specific case of $M=Fr(V)$, $\mathscr A = \mathscr A_v$ and $\mathscr B = \mathscr A_w$, we have that $\mathscr M(\mathscr A_v)$ $=$ $\mathscr M(\mathscr A_w)$. This is the same sense as in Guess 1 that $Fr_v(V)$ and $Fr_w(V)$ are "identical".

**Question C**: (I happened to notice [Problem 6.3 of Volume 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpLbn.png) as I was looking up [Problem 6.1 of Volume 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpDAz.png)) Is [Problem 6.3 of Volume 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpLbn.png) precisely proving the frame manifold of Volume 3 is well-defined?

- Solution at the back of the book (which says the maximal atlases are the same): [Solution to Problem 6.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVjfM.png)